# vsftpd - Load users folders paths from database

Tags: centos, vsftpd

I am looking for a way to configure vsftpd for allow access to folders depending to database values.

I explain:

- I have a database containing users ftp login and password. She contains too a folder path of a folder the user can access.
- In this database too, i have for each user values that say if the user can access to a specified common folder.

I want that when the user connect, he has access to his folder defined in db and if he has the right in db the common folder.